# Why is my laptop suddenly laggy

Tags: windows-10, laptop, performance

**Specs**

Dell XPS 9560 (bought new, 2017)
15" FHD | Windows 10 | 16 GB RAM | 512 GB SSD (Toshiba) | i7-7700HQ | Nvidia GTX 1050

I am generally quite prompt about software updates, both OS and devices/components.

**Usage**
6-12 hours a day. Mostly programming, general browsing (lots of videos on YouTube). (Nothing that makes the fans go BRRRRR... . ) Shut down when not in use. Almost always right next to an open window in reasonable temperatures.

**Symptoms**

It started about a couple of months ago, when I started noticing the page loading was weird. For example, YouTube would load (and still does) as if my connection was slow, in a kind of "layered" way: the background and YT logo would appear; then a bunch of "empty placeholders" for the video thumbnails, channel logo, title etc; and the finally, in a staggered manner, the actual thumbnails, titles, descriptions and the side bar. All of this now takes 5-10 seconds. Although video playback itself is smooth. That's with Firefox with a bunch of add-ons. But this happens even in Edge, which doesn't have any add-ons and is a browser that I hardly if ever use.

I notice similar slowness and jittery behaviour in other applications:

- Explorer is slower
- Acrobat Reader - the recent documents show the thumbnails after a few seconds
- WSL2 - even `ls`-like simple commands have a minor but noticeable delay
- VS Code - remote WSL extensions and a single file takes ~2 minutes to load. File navigation is not the smoothest.
- Task Manager - It opens, freezes with a bunch of numbers for a couple of seconds, the app icons appear, and then it comes to life.

**Tests**

All of the tests I have run indicate that there is "nothing wrong" with the hardware.

- Preboot diagnostic test
- One of those Dell programs that runs tests on hardware

Task Manager show reasonable numbers despite the lag. ~50% RAM and around 20-30% CPU. Nothing is heating up or making a sound.

The only place where I have seen a large change since purchasing the laptop is the **CrystalDiskMark** reports of the SSD.

**Jan 2018**

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
CrystalDiskMark 6.0.0 x64 (C) 2007-2017 hiyohiyo
                          Crystal Dew World : https://crystalmark.info/
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
* MB/s = 1,000,000 bytes/s [SATA/600 = 600,000,000 bytes/s]
* KB = 1000 bytes, KiB = 1024 bytes

   Sequential Read (Q= 32,T= 1) :  3019.220 MB/s
  Sequential Write (Q= 32,T= 1) :   455.855 MB/s
  Random Read 4KiB (Q=  8,T= 8) :   747.411 MB/s [ 182473.4 IOPS]
 Random Write 4KiB (Q=  8,T= 8) :   462.769 MB/s [ 112980.7 IOPS]
  Random Read 4KiB (Q= 32,T= 1) :   345.998 MB/s [  84472.2 IOPS]
 Random Write 4KiB (Q= 32,T= 1) :   276.534 MB/s [  67513.2 IOPS]
  Random Read 4KiB (Q=  1,T= 1) :    10.671 MB/s [   2605.2 IOPS]
 Random Write 4KiB (Q=  1,T= 1) :    48.380 MB/s [  11811.5 IOPS]

  Test : 1024 MiB [C: 14.3% (66.2/461.5 GiB)] (x5)  [Interval=5 sec]
  Date : 2018/01/06 16:13:40
    OS : Windows 10  [10.0 Build 16299] (x64)
```

**Jan 2022**

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
CrystalDiskMark 6.0.0 x64 (C) 2007-2017 hiyohiyo
                          Crystal Dew World : https://crystalmark.info/
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
* MB/s = 1,000,000 bytes/s [SATA/600 = 600,000,000 bytes/s]
* KB = 1000 bytes, KiB = 1024 bytes

   Sequential Read (Q= 32,T= 1) :  1393.578 MB/s
  Sequential Write (Q= 32,T= 1) :   713.814 MB/s
  Random Read 4KiB (Q=  8,T= 8) :   270.359 MB/s [  66005.6 IOPS]
 Random Write 4KiB (Q=  8,T= 8) :   178.721 MB/s [  43633.1 IOPS]
  Random Read 4KiB (Q= 32,T= 1) :    61.309 MB/s [  14968.0 IOPS]
 Random Write 4KiB (Q= 32,T= 1) :    47.580 MB/s [  11616.2 IOPS]
  Random Read 4KiB (Q=  1,T= 1) :    18.907 MB/s [   4616.0 IOPS]
 Random Write 4KiB (Q=  1,T= 1) :    24.941 MB/s [   6089.1 IOPS]

  Test : 1024 MiB [C: 52.8% (243.7/461.5 GiB)] (x5)  [Interval=5 sec]
  Date : 2022/01/23 18:37:43
    OS : Windows 10  [10.0 Build 19044] (x64)
```

**CrystalDiskInfo** shows the status as being "Good" at 84%.

S.M.A.R.T. data

```
-- S.M.A.R.T. --------------------------------------------------------------
ID RawValues(6) Attribute Name
01 000000000000 Critical Warning
02 000000000134 Composite Temperature
03 000000000064 Available Spare
04 00000000000A Available Spare Threshold
05 000000000010 Percentage Used
06 000001EED7C3 Data Units Read
07 000001FA6EBE Data Units Written
08 0000245C4BC5 Host Read Commands
09 000025692C94 Host Write Commands
0A 000000000B99 Controller Busy Time
0B 000000001422 Power Cycles
0C 0000000023EA Power On Hours
0D 00000000006A Unsafe Shutdowns
0E 000000000000 Media and Data Integrity Errors
0F 000000000000 Number of Error Information Log Entries
```

Anything else that I should check?

I hadn't made any drastic changes to the laptop (HW/SW) before I started noticing this. Just the usual updates, that's all. The programs I use are mainstream and well-maintained, nothing iffy.

I'm not sure what is causing the problem, but as much as I used to love working with this laptop it now seems like "chore" to do basic things. It is still my daily driver, but I would love to get rid of this laggy behaviour and regain some of the speed. Any help appreciated.

P.S.: I'm asking for ways to set my current laptop right, and not if I should replace it or if I made a bad choice. ;-)

Comment: What build of Windows 10 do you have installed? It's suspicious your read & write performance took more than a 50% decrease. Although 4 years is a good amount of time for a SSD. You might consider just replacing it.

Comment: Just to comment, in my experience when SSD is lagging (Assuming there’s no significant wear) a sanitize operation on it restores it back to near factory speeds. Specially those SSDs that do not have enough DRAM or are DRAM-less.  In case you plan to buy a new SSD you would need to go thru the process of either a clean install of Windows 10 or imaging and restoring on new SSD. So, if you really are taking that path, try Sanitize first. This is data destructive so imaging/backup and restore or clean install is required. Continued....

Comment: Check if Dell or SSD vendor has provided any tools for secure erase or sanitize operation. Moreover, if possible, try running Live Linux and check if Youtube, disk I/O and other such operations again lag or not.

Comment: @Ramhound OS build: 19044.1466.

Comment: @patkim, thanks for the suggestions. Replacing the SSD is one of the things I considered, but I just want to make sure that what I'm observing are effects of a worn out drive. I will look into sanitizing.

Comment: What is the SMART data of the disk?

Comment: @harrymc I have added it to the original post.

Comment: Your disk is in perfect shape with no hardware errors of any kind. Try doing `chkdsk` for software errors.

Comment: @harrymc `Windows has scanned the file system and found no problems.
No further action is required.`

Comment: Good - no disk problems. Please check now if this still happens when you boot in [Safe Mode with Networking](https://support.shaw.ca/t5/internet-articles/how-to-boot-your-computer-in-safe-mode-with-networking-windows/ta-p/5450).

Comment: Hi @harrymc, I could only perform limited testing in "safe mode with networking", because despite the name, I had no access to a connection. (I even tried explicitly choosing the option in msconfig to no avail. I didn't have the networking button in the login screen.) I also couldn't access WSL2. That said, whatever I could access behaved comparatively faster.

Comment: This means that your network adapter uses a non-Microsoft driver so cannot be used by pure Windows. Try the less violent [clean boot](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows-da2f9573-6eec-00ad-2f8a-a97a1807f3dd) without disabling network stuff. If this works better, you could return startups until reaching the problem product.